# Alignment issue of images

Tags: c#, printing

I request you to be in patience to read this till the end.

**Back ground** :
I have an app that accepts a file from usb and prints the formatted data into graph plots via printer , when user clicks a button - PRINT

**Process** : It is a ever running application. so user removes the drive after every file is printed, copies new files, insert in application , clicks the PRINT button.

**Problem** : first time everything is ok. when user removes the drive, return with a new file, alignment of all the images are gone when i am printing.

eg : a bitmap is drawn at right end of paper, will be shifted left on the next time.

**I tried** : resets the `PrintDocument` objects on every PRINT button click. (No use). Tried an application restart every time PRINT button clicks : which works as expected. so i am having the assumption that, it is something related to application start up.

I know it is a vague question. I am confused about which data is to be presented here. Since i don't know which part is making problem. So please ask for clarifications, or which code part is needed for verification and I will post.

**Edit 1,2** : Code for explanation

```
var trackChart3 = new Chart();
var chart3Area = new ChartArea { Name = "chart3" };
trackChart3.ChartAreas.Add(chart3Area);

var locChart3 = new Point(-70, 162);
var chartSize = new Size(90, 60);
var chart3Rect = new Rectangle(locChart3, chartSize);
trackChart3.Printing.PrintPaint(e.Graphics, chart3Rect);
```

this prints a chart at right side of the page for the first time(Application startup printing). But after drive removal and insertion it will be gone to original -70, which is not in the paper.